# How to customize Visual Studio C/C++ indentation/formatting beyond None/Block/Smart (Like Eclipse Can)

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio

Is there a way to customize Visual Studio indentation/formatting in detail?  There seems to be just three options: None, Block, Smart (in Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Tabs).  There are a couple more options under Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting, but these don't provide the the options I am looking for (e.g. how much to indent line wrapping).

In contrast there are a huge number of options to configure in formatting Eclipse, as described [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Format-Settings-in-Eclipse) (e.g. a line wrapping tab with various options), so I would expect there to be some similar configuration options in Visual Studio.

Comment: This is more a superuser question than a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting is all there is built-in to VS.

An alternative that's smarter is clang-format: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html. There's an installer that integrates in into Visual Studio for you: http://llvm.org/builds/. Note that it only deals with the file's actual formatting rather than things like soft-wrapping lines. Soft-wrapping source code is horrific anyway.

Comment: Note that you can place a .clang-format in one of the parent directories of the source and the (VS plugin) Tools > ClangFormat (or the equivalent Ctr+R, Ctr+F) uses that file instead of the default.  It is easy to get started with the examples at http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#examples (e.g. the visual studio one is especially simple to get started with).

Comment: For the plugin configuration try also Tools->Options->LLVM/Clang->ClangFormat as described at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668517/how-to-feed-visual-studio-clang-format-plugin-with-clang-format-file

Comment: Too bad the clang-format plugin doesn't format text live as you type, otherwise this would be perfect for me.